# how to retrieve info from datastore using google app engine and display it in a list view on an android app using java?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to make an android app that retrieves info from google app engine datastore and display it as a listview in the android app..can anyone help me out with some code or explain what exactly needs to be done for this purpose? i have already made modifications on the server side to store data on the datastore..what i dont know is how to get that data onto the android app..i am using eclipse indigo and language is java

EDIT : I am putting my code that i am using to retrieve a set of strings from datastore and put it in a list view...the code is gonna look all haywire but i request you to bear with me and explain how exactly to write it..presently the application is force-closing whenever i get to the page where this list of retrieved strings is supposed to be displayed...

```
public class Display extends ListActivity
{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;

static String[] title;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displaylayout);


    MyRequestFactory factory = (MyRequestFactory)Util.getRequestFactory(Display.this,MyRequestFactory.class);
    FebfourthRequest febfourthRequest = factory.febfourthRequest();
    final List<TrialDBProxy> list= new ArrayList<TrialDBProxy>();
       febfourthRequest.queryTrialDBs().fire(new Receiver<List<TrialDBProxy>>() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<TrialDBProxy> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            list.addAll(arg0);
        }   


    });


    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        title[i] = list.get(i).getMessage();
    }

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    data = new Vector<RowData>();

    for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++)
    {
        rd = new RowData(i,title[i]);
        data.add(rd);
    }
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 };

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor mCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null,      null, null, null);
    ListAdapter adapter = new       SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.displaylayout,mCursor,title,to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
private class RowData 
{
protected int mId;
protected String mTitle;

RowData(int id,String title)
{
mId=id;
mTitle = title;

}
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return mId+" "+mTitle;
    }
}    '
```

NOTE : TrialDB is the file that contains all my fields that i want to store on the datastore.
displaylayout is the xml file where i have created a listview.
i am guessing the main part where i have to put code for displaying stuff is in the onCreate() method. 
PLEASE HELP !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already *a very good starting point for learning* both Google App Engine and Android Development.

I may write **the steps to follow**:

1. Write a Google App Engine application **which reads data from datastore and gives as JSON**. You can use GAE web framework, or maybe Django. After doing that, you will have a url which gives you your data in your browser.
2. Write **a hello world application for Android**. This step gives you an opportunity to understand and setup Android development environment.
3. Write an Android app which uses a listview with static data.
4. **Extend your Android app with calling a single simple url from web**, then print it on your screen.
5. **Extend your application via calling your Google App Engine application url inside your app**. Now you have your datastore data in your app.
6. Populate your listview with your data.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply...i already have done some of the stuff u mentioned..is there any way of doing this without using JSON ?? i am using app engine connected android project..if JSON is the best option..could u elaborate on how to include that with a little code?

Comment: JSON is not the only option, you can use any data transfer data structure such as XML or your own implementation. JSON is simple, lightweight and supported by many languages/libraries. Try some parts, and ask other questions that you experience. You can give vote to answers if they are helpful for you.

Comment: well referring your previous answer...i have already done the first 3 steps..could u tell me how to do the 4th step ? how do i call a url and print stuff on the app ?

Comment: The first part of this article explains simply: http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/ If my answer is helpful for you, consider voting.

Comment: while the article u showed was very helpful, i am looking for getting data from google app engine rather than a PHP server...if u could help me to that end..would be gr8!
PS : I don't really know how to "vote" for an answer..if u cud tell me that too... :D

Comment: In that article, there is this line: HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/food.php");
 Just change address, write your Google App Engine url instead of http://127.0.0.1/food.php.     For voting: "Click the large up or down arrows to the left of each post."

Comment: well it seems i need a reputation of 15 to vote..so sorry mate ! anyways..in my program..i am calling queryTrialDBs() method..thing is that method is supposed to return all the elements in the datastore but i have defined the return type as List<TrialDBProxy> which i had to because of all the constraints of eclipse that the android files can't access the server files directly..so basically all i want to fetch from the datastore is a set of strings...my main class that defines the "columns" in datastore also has just one field that is of string type..

Comment: now i want to ask how can i display this List<TrialDBProxy> that queryTrialDBs() returns and display it on a list view? do i need to add some type cast or something? how do i do it??

Comment: This is a different subject and needs a different question. Search in Stackoverflow first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208214/how-to-process-a-query-result-so-as-to-display-it-as-a-listview-in-android